# How to target media queries for Samsung tab 8.4 inch

Tags: css

How to target media queries for Samsung tab 8.4 inch.
my code is

```
    @media (device-width: 800px) and (device-height: 1280px)
```

when first appearance media query is getting affected. once changed the orientation from Portrait to Landscape and again back to Portrait, style is not getting affected.

Device Specification :
    http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_s_8_4-6439.php

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I can't test my solution on physical device, but you can play with orientation:

**Landscape mode**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 1280px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles for landscape*/
}
```

**Portrait mode**

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 800x) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles for portrait*/
}
```

Notice, that different browsers (chrome, android native browser, firefox etc.) handle media queries in different way. For example if you use:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px)
```

it would work on Desktop Chrome browser and on android smartphone browser,  but not on Safari on iPhone. To make it work on Safari you have to use:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px)
```

The conclusion is that you need test your media queries on physical devices :)
For more information, check this page: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/